# What is the spell-out form of ‘FUPA’ as an acronym for ‘a protruding lower belly’?

Tags: acronyms

Tina Fey lists up 26 ‘deficiencies’ that women are buying a product to correct them, which starts with the first seven:

-big pores

-oily T-zone

-cankles

-lunchlady arms

-fivehead,

-nipples too big,

and then,

-**FUPA** (an acronym for a protruding lower belly)

in her latest million-seller book, “Tina Fey: Bossypants.”

I have no idea about what words FUPA do account for as an acronym. What are they?

Comment: I am actually rather proud of the fact that I had never heard of most of these terms. And I am also rather glad to be detached from a society which obsesses over what people look like. I am just wondering where Tina Fey might put 'pea-brained' in her list of problems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's "Fat Upper Pubic Area" according to [Urban Dictionary](http://tr.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=FUPA).

Comment: Is it a current English word? Does most people understand it?

Comment: I hope not. Likewise for "fivehead" and "cankles".

Comment: As I understand UD's description, in BrE a FUPA is referred to as a gunt.

Comment: Likely its use became a fad in Schenectady, or some such, to the point where Urban dictionary picked up on it, and now it's dying the slow death of unloved internet phraseology.

Comment: @MattE.Эллен -- and these days, three years later, FUPA is forgotten and gunt lives on...